# text wrap grows up, height property grows down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So the fundamental issue is that if the **text of a block exceeds the width** and turns into 2 lines, the extra height of the block is **added to the *top***, but when I adjust the **height of a block in CSS, that height is added to the *bottom***.  Here's a screenshot of the issue I'm facing:

[image]

Because the description of the plates on the right spans 3 lines, the div grows upwards.  My thought was that if I can change the height of the **h5** to it's height when the text spans 3 lines (72px). If I do this the **h5** grows *downwards*.

[image]

I'll start by just posting the html from my template and css of the live page.  If it'll help I'll add the js that generates this grid later.  Sorry for any extraneous code :)

Thanks in advance!

```
<a href='{{firstdibs}}' target='_blank'>
  <div class='storeItem'>
    <b class='sold {{sold}}'>SOLD</b>
    <img src='1stdibs/{{image}}.jpeg' />
    <div class='layer'>
      <div class='hide' id='itemDescription'>
        <h5>{{title}}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

div.storeItem {
    width: 28%;
    /* height: 200px; */
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000000;*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 2.5% 20px 2.5%;

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #aaaaaa;
}

div.storeItem:hover{

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #444444;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn .2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation: fadeIn .2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div.storeItem img{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

.storeItem h5{
    font-family: MohaveTest;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 80%;
    font-weight: 200;
    /*font-style: italic;*/
    line-height: 120%;
    font-size: 20px;
    }

.storeItem p{
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 80%;
}

.hide{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: rgba(161,91,73,1);
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` tag's default `display` state is `inline`. Try using `display: block` on the `<a>` tag or wrap into custom `<div`

Comment: I did this but it didn't affect anything.  That's not really the issue. Also FWIW I need the display to be inline-block so that I can create the grid.

Comment: basically I'd like to expand the height of the h5 to fit 3 lines, so if the text is less than 3 lines the height of the h5 and the entire div will stay the same